# weighted multiply with OpenCL, uncovered full range?

Tags: c++, c++11, opencl, gpgpu, opencv3.0

I am writing a kernel in order to process a weighhted multiplication by the index.
I mean `i*vec[i]`.
I would like to use as efficiently as possible my *compute units* (`CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS`) without exeding the max of my *work group size*(`CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`).

So for doing this I wrote the following kernel :

wght_mul.cl:

```
#ifdef MU_ND

__kernel void kmu(__global const int* _hist, const ulong _total, __global int* _tmp)
{
    int id = get_global_id(0)*kercn;
    const int lid = get_local_id(0);
    const int gid = get_group_id(0);

    const int gsz = get_global_size(0);
    const int lsz = get_local_size(0);

    int sum = 0;

    #if kercn == 4
    int4 sum4 = (int4)(0.f);
    #elif kercn == 8
    int8 sum8 = (int8)(0.f);
    #endif

    for(int grain = CU*WGS*kercn;id<_total;id+=grain)
    {
        #if kercn == 1
        sum += *(_hist+id) * id;
        #elif kercn == 4
        int4 idx = (int4)(id,id+1,id+2,id+3);
        int4 val = vload4(0,_hist+id);

        val*=idx;

        sum4 += val;
        #elif kercn == 8
        int8 idx = (int8)(id,id+1,id+2,id+3,id+4,id+5,id+6,id+7);
        int8 val = vload8(0,_hist+id);

        val*=idx;

        sum8 += val;
        #else
        #pragma unroll
        for(int i =0;i<kercn;i++)
            sum += *(_hist+id+i) * (id+i);

        #endif
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    #if kercn == 4
    sum = sum4.s0 + sum4.s1 + sum4.s2 + sum4.s3;
    #elif kercn == 8
    sum = sum8.s0 + sum8.s1 + sum8.s2 + sum8.s3 + sum8.s4 + sum8.s5 + sum8.s6 + sum8.s7;
    #endif

    *(_tmp+gid) += sum;

    printf("kercn %d\n",kercn);

    //printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",id,lid,gid,gsz,lsz);
}

#endif
```

Here is demo between what I would like to have and what I get :

main.cpp :

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat vec = cv::Mat::zeros(1,65536,CV_32SC1);
    cv::Mat idx = cv::Mat::zeros(1,65536,CV_32SC1);

    std::iota(idx.begin<int>(),idx.end<int>(),0);

    std::for_each(vec.begin<int>(),vec.end<int>(),[&](int& v){ v = cv::theRNG().uniform(0,1000);});


    // MY CODE

    cv::UMat uvec;
    cv::UMat utmp;

    vec.copyTo(uvec);

    std::ifstream file_stream("../test/wght_mul.cl");
    std::ostringstream file_buf;

    file_buf<<file_stream.rdbuf();

    cv::ocl::ProgramSource source(file_buf.str());

    const cv::ocl::Device& dev = cv::ocl::Device::getDefault();

    std::size_t wgs = dev.maxWorkGroupSize();
    std::size_t compute_units = dev.maxComputeUnits();

    std::size_t kercn = 8;

    std::size_t globalsize = wgs*compute_units;
    std::size_t localsize = wgs;


    cv::ocl::Kernel k("kmu",source,cv::format("-D MU_ND -D CU=%ld -D WGS=%ld -D kercn=%ld ",compute_units,wgs,kercn));

    k.run(1,&globalsize,&localsize,false);


    utmp = cv::UMat::zeros(compute_units,1,CV_32SC1);

    k.args(cv::ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(uvec),uvec.total(),cv::ocl::KernelArg::PtrWriteOnly(utmp));

    k.run(1,&globalsize,&localsize,false);

    std::cout<<"utmp : "<<utmp.getMat(cv::ACCESS_RW)<<std::endl;

    // RESULT EXPECTED

    cv::multiply(vec,idx,vec);

    std::cout<<"result expected : "<<cv::sum(vec)(0)<<" results using my kernel : "<<cv::sum(utmp)(0)<<std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The execution work but the result is not the one I expect.

So my questions are :

- What's wrong with my code ?
- I observe if I set the variable `kercn` to 4 all my compute units are used, otherwise only half of them are used. Is it better to use all the compute units ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should have actually much more workgroups than compute units. When a work-group is stalled due to a memory read for example, then another work-group can be executed in the meantime. Please be more specific about the current result and the expected result.

Comment: Thank for your answer. The expected result I generate with the sequential code give the result I would like to have using the parallel code.
I know must have more workgroups than compute units.
The idea on the back of this code was to understant how to do a parallel reduce using opencl.
This code is highly inspired from opencv's ocl_clachist1 function (module/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp).
So if you pay attention get_group_id(0) (for this code) with kercn == vec.total()/globalsize you'll never have an id higher than the number of compute units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know that local variables in the kernel function uses a register file which is very limited in space. Using 8 bytes for each local variable instead of 4 bytes would cause each work item to require more registers. That shared register file among the GPU cores won't be sufficient to activate all cores at the same time.

You can use GPU Profiling tools to find out the required register file in each case and optimize it out.